# How to create RSA key with Expiry and/or Name using BouncyCastle in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle

Is it possible to create a RSA key using BouncyCastle with an expiry and/or the name of the key holder? Right now, I've managed to only successfully create a key with no expiry and no name - just an e-mail address.

Than you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, or your claim that you created a key with an email address. You can create any metadata you want and associate the metadata with your key using any scheme you want. If you are talking about X.509 certificates then please be specific about that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk basically the way you can create an OpenPGP key pair using Kleopatra - is that possible using BouncyCastle in C#? Because BouncyCastle's API only allows setting a username as metadata for the RSA key, nothing else.

Comment: Show us the code you have and we can try to help you